# How can I make this cylinder go along a curve object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, curve-modifier

I have a curve I made to match the shape of this chair leg that I need. [image]

When I try to add the curve modifier to the cylinder the cylinder doesn't do what I need it to do. I've reset the transforms for the cylinder and I've applied a bunch of loop cuts to it and still, it doesn't bend along the curve. Please help.[image]

Comment: The cylinder needs subdivisions down its length? Hard to tell, from your picture. ( I would recommend forgetting the cylinder anyway, and using the curve's native Round Bevel setting in its Data tab, Geometry panel. )

Comment: @RobinBetts I just tried it and it works how I need it too. Thank you so much!